# How to implement simple audio playback in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I'm developing a simple Node.js chat application with socket.io and express and would like to play a short audio file on a button click event. The relevant setup is as follows:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendfile('index.html');
});

http.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000, function() {
  console.log("Server running on port 5000");
});
```

And this is the relevenat index.html code:

```
<button onclick="document.getElementById('myTune').play()">Play Music</button>
<audio id="myTune">
  <source src="sound.mp3">
</audio>
```

This works fine on the basic html file when run in the browser but not when I run it in Node.  I have a feeling there's some special set up required with Node/express to be able to access the sound file but I'm not sure what this is exactly. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Yes, there is an extra set up required. Take a look at [this module](https://github.com/obastemur/mediaserver).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your server code it is not clear how do you make your mp3 file available for the browser. Try serving it as static content. Add

`app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));`

and place sound.mp3 into the public directory